# How do you view the current spatial index grid size for a file geodatabase feature class?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arccatalog, spatial-index

I am receiving an "The spatial index grid size is invalid." error during a copy/paste of polygon features in ArcMap and I successfully corrected it with AddSpatialIndex. But in an effort to figure out how and why I ended up with invalid grid size, I thought I would start with the actual grid size.

I would like to know what the current grid size is and I don't see a way to view that in ArcCatalog.  Is it possible to view the current grid size of a file geodatabase featureclass?

Comment: Not sure if you can find the grid size in the metadata ("description") tab in ArcCatalog? It may be something that is populated automatically. I think there's an indexes tab in the properties window too but I imagine you've already looked there.

Comment: You can calculate the grid index using this:  http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Calculate_Default_Spatial_Grid_Index/00170000002n000000/  and the results will appear in the geoprprocessing results window.

Comment: @thehealingprocess: I forgot about the metadata! But I don't see the spatial grid info there.... it does specify if one exists.

Comment: @evv_gis: wouldn't that be the grid size of the new grid? not the existing one?